# Cryptic Firebase error during batch write process failure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm trying to write 50 records to firestore using a batch write/update. This works fine on my mac with node/js admin sdk. Running that same code on a VM in a docker container running Ubuntu/Node image I get a cryptic error related to gRPC, which apparently Firebase uses under the hood for parts of it's sdk. This error appears in the catch block of batch.commit(). I'm not even sure where to begin debugging this.

```
TypeError: Incorrectly typed arguments to startBatch
api_1         |     at _startBatchIfReady (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:752:10)
api_1         |     at Object.final_requester.start (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:801:21)
api_1         |     at InterceptingCall._callNext (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:421:43)
api_1         |     at InterceptingCall.start (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:456:8)
api_1         |     at next (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:453:22)
api_1         |     at InterceptingCall._callNext (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:428:12)
api_1         |     at InterceptingCall.start (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:456:8)
api_1         |     at ServiceClient.Client.makeUnaryRequest (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:537:21)
api_1         |     at ServiceClient.method_func (/app/server/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:952:43)
api_1         |     at /app/server/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:150:41
```

executing function

```
try {
        const eventsJson = await getMetadataFile();

        // load all events into the database
        eventsJson.forEach((event, idx) => {
            let batch = db.batch();
            let newEventRef = COLLECTION_REF.doc();
            batch.set(newEventRef, event);
            batch.update(newEventRef, { eventId: newEventRef.id });
            batch.commit().catch(error => {
                console.log("BATCH UPDATE ERROR:", error)
            });
        });
        res.json(eventsJson);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("BATCH ERROR:", error)
        formatResponse(res, 'error', error);
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what the cause of your error is but I don't think you need to use batch here. You can collapse your set() and update() into just set() by saving Object.assign({}, event, { eventId: newEventRef.id });

Comment: Also, are you sure you need to explicitly store the id of your document as a field given that firestore is already associating your document with that id?

Comment: I'd say that grpc error is not related to this code. Though you have 2 hidden problems with your code. 1. You're defining batch inside the loop, so effectively each set+update creates another batch - perhaps not what you meant. Move batch declaration out of the loop. 2. As said by Tom, you can replace set+update with one set `batch.set(ref, {...event, id: ref.id})`. Firestore has a limit or 1 sustainable write per second to a document. You may argue if making 2 instant writes for 50 documents at 1 moment is within the limit or not.